# Docker run mapping ports does not work in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker

I am using a Docker version *18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40* on ubuntu *16.04* and trying to run the command:

```
docker run -p 4000:5000 Repository_Name
```

It's not opening in a browser using `https://localhost:4000`.

But if I run with

```
docker run --net host -p 4000:5000 Repository_Name
```

It's opening in a browser using `https://localhost:5000`.

I want to change from Expose port say `5000` to host port `4000`. so that in a browser I can run it using `https://localhost:4000`. Please explain how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Please post the Dockerfile. My initial suspicion would be that whatever app you're running is listening on `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` in the container so the former command would not work (as container has it's own net stack, localhost in container != localhost on host) but the latter would (as it's using the host net stack and localhost on host == localhost in container).

Comment: Docker File-----

Comment: # Instructions copied from - https://hub.docker.com/_/python/
FROM python:3-onbuild

# tell the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 5000

# run the command
CMD ["python", "solar_data.py"]

Comment: I don't see any Dockerfile added, but what's `solar_data.py`? Can you post the relevant part of that (where it actually runs the webserver) from that file as well please?

Comment: Docker File--------------

FROM python:3-onbuild

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ['command for running my app']

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From your reply, I am able to understand that localhost in a container port is different from localhost on host port while running docker run command. As my application is running on 127.0.0.1:5000, that is why my app is not running on docker which behaves like 192.168.99.100:4000. so if I change my docker run command like docker run --net host -p 5000:5000 Repository_Name. It will be working fine as it will take 127.0.0.1:5000 as a host port.